# how to display dc.js graph using django

Tags: javascript, django, d3.js, dc.js

I'm making a graph using the Dimensional Charting javascript library dc.js,
which is based on d3 and crossfilter. i am new in dc.js library.i am trying to display the graph using django framework for python but graph can not be display.this same code used for simple html then graph is display but django cant be display.i am using hard coded data pass to the graph.I use the following code to produce the graph below

`views.py`

```
def testing(request):

    return render(request, 'test1.html')
    enter code here
```

`test1.html`

```
{% block content %}
{% load staticfiles %}
<head>
<link href="{% static 'css/dc.css' %}"  rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/d3.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/crossfilter.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="{% static 'js/dc.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var yearRingChart   = dc.pieChart("#chart-ring-year");

    var spendHistChart  = dc.barChart("#chart-hist-spend");
    var spenderRowChart = dc.rowChart("#chart-row-spenders");



    var spendData = [
    {Name: 'Mr A', Spent: '$40', Year: 2011},
    {Name: 'Mr B', Spent: '$10', Year: 2011},
    {Name: 'Mr C', Spent: '$40', Year: 2011},
    {Name: 'Mr A', Spent: '$70', Year: 2012},
    {Name: 'Mr B', Spent: '$20', Year: 2012},
    {Name: 'Mr B', Spent: '$50', Year: 2013},
    {Name: 'Mr C', Spent: '$30', Year: 2013}
    ];


    spendData.forEach(function(d) {

    d.Spent = d.Spent.match(/\d+/);
      });


    var ndx = crossfilter(spendData),
    yearDim  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return +d.Year;}),
    spendDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return Math.floor(d.Spent/10);}),
    nameDim  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.Name;}),
    spendPerYear = yearDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.Spent;}),
    spendPerName = nameDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.Spent;}),
    spendHist    = spendDim.group().reduceCount();

    yearRingChart
        .width(200).height(200)
        .dimension(yearDim)
        .group(spendPerYear)
        .innerRadius(50);

    spendHistChart
        .width(300).height(200)
        .dimension(spendDim)
        .group(spendHist)
        .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,10]))
        .elasticY(true);

    spendHistChart.xAxis().tickFormat(function(d) {return d*10}); // convert back to base    unit
    spendHistChart.yAxis().ticks(2);

    spenderRowChart
        .width(350).height(200)
        .dimension(nameDim)
        .group(spendPerName)
       .elasticX(true);


    yearRingChart.render();
    spendHistChart.render();
    spenderRowChart.render();

</script>
</head>
<div id="chart-ring-year"></div>
<div id="chart-hist-spend"></div>
<div id="chart-row-spenders"></div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Which error displaying in firebug ?

Comment: @PriyankPatel  Error cant be display.

Comment: As u said , if u don't use django then graph is displaying correctly so make sure js and css are loading correctly . use firebug `Net` to check whether its loading . If its not displaying then 404 is displayed in development server.

Comment: @PriyankPatel  404 error display. how to fix it

Comment: make sure path to  folders `css` and `js` listed in `STATICFILES_DIRS` in your settings file .

Comment: @PriyankPatel   '304 not modified ' this error message is display

Comment: Thats not error. page is coming correctly from cache memory . your js and css should be loading now .

Comment: @PriyankPatel but graph cant be display

Comment: Use firebug for error message.